# Detect hand gestures using Accelerometer

Tags: .net, gesture, uwp, microsoft-band

I'm currently trying to figure out swiping gestures using the Microsoft Band 2s accelerometer/Gyroscope.

My implementation is quite childish: I get the biggest change across all axes in accelerometer values since last values update. This is very inaccurate and doesn't register until you move with specific speed (above threshold). Another option that springs to mind is to measure the change for more than one value difference, but I can see this being not so accurate either.

Is there a ready library that already does that in .NET? if not, any resources to get me in that right direction (no pun intended)?

Thank you,

Comment: I've never heard of a .NET librairy that do this, you may work by yourself this time. But if you do so, let me know how it goes, thx

Comment: @SvenBorden read my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AzureMl ended up being too expensive and restrictive for the project.

I moved to using [Wiigee](http://www.wiigee.org/); it was initially developed for the WiiMote but with a bit of tweaking it works with other devices with accelerometer sensor.

It's written in Java, so you'll need use a server to communicate between the two programs (I used [SignalR](http://signalr.net))

Answer (score 0):

you can start using this very detailed article about detecting a "tap" gesture using the accelerometer

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-accelerometer-in-windows-8-metro-style-app-and-a-case-study-of-tap-detection

You can use the same technic to detect other gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an experiment on [AzureML](https://studio.azureml.net/) as I was in a particular situation; using the band I was limited to Universal App ([UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx)), and I cannot execute .py script on the platform.

I tried using a library on WPF to allow the usage of UWP libraries on WPF, but it had a weird I couldn't figure out.

I came across libsvm, which seemed sufficient for my needs, but I was pressed on time and hadn't the time to investigate it.

Hope this helps.